# How to get the desired output using CSS classes?

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar

I have the following code snippet from (.cshtml code):

```
eventSources: [
{
    ...
    className: 'events-main',
    url: 'Home/GetEvents'.
    dataType: 'json',
    ...
}
],

eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
    if(event.imageurl != null)
    {
        className = 'mCS_img_loaded',
        // some more properties
    }

    else
    {
        className =  'no-image',
        // some moreproperties
    }
}
```

CSS Classes (StyleSheet.css):

```
.calendar-events {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color:transparent!important;
}

.mCS_img_loaded{
    background-color: transparent!important;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.no-image{
    margin: 20px 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color:black;
}
```

I want the `calendar-events` class to be applied on both the cases: whether the `imageurl` is present or not. and, the other two classes, `mCS_img_loaded` and `no-image` to be applied depending on the `if-else` condition.

On writing the code in this way, I am getting the images in a circle, and content for `no-image` in `white` background. I need it in `black` background.

Am I writing the code in the right way?

Comment: remove `!important` from `background-color` and maybe add your class names like this: `className = 'calendar-events mCS_img_loaded'` and `className =  'calendar-events no-image'`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I applied your changes, but the content other than the image is still coming with white/transparent background.The contents apart from the image is just simple text.

Comment: your code doesn't actually apply your classname to anything! You just create a variable containing the class name, but then do nothing with it. You have to set that class on your target element... did you just miss this part out? It's obviously an important part of the process, e.g. we don't know for certain which element within the event element you're applying it to, or whether you apply it to the outer event element itself.